# Post dynamic twitter updates

Tags: javascript, twitter, html

I currently have some script on my page that parses title/artist information from my online radio station. I am displaying it as plain text in html by using

```
<span id="song_title"></span>
```

How can I take this dynamic information that is going into the span id and use it for a "post to twitter" link so listeners can share the current song title on Twitter?

I did some research and found a few variations on posting to twitter, but I had no luck with posting this dynamic text.

Here's the script code:

```
<!-- Begin Now Playing Script -->
            <script>
            (function () {
                // we need a JSON parser, if it does not exist, load it
                if (typeof JSON == "undefined") {
                    var s = document.createElement("script");
                    // json2.js retrieved from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
                    s.src = "json2.js";
                    document.getElementsByTagName("head").appendChild(s);
                }
            })();
            var song_ends = 0;
            function update_song () {
                if ((new Date).getTime() < song_ends) {
                    // use cached result as the song has not ended yet
                    return;
                }
                var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                // IE compatbility:
                var textContent = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
                req.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (req.readyState == 4) {
                        var song = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
                        if (song.title) {
                            var img = document.getElementById("song_image");
                                if(song.image.src){
                            img.alt = song.image.alt;
                            img.src = song.image.src;
                            img.width = 100;
                            img.height = 100;
                                }else{
                            img.src="images/default_art.png";
                            img.width = 100;
                            img.height = 100;
                                }
                            document.getElementById("song_title")[textContent]  = song.title ;
                            document.getElementById("song_artist")[textContent] = song.artist;
                            document.getElementById("song_next")[textContent]  = song.next ;
                            // store the end date in javascript date format
                            song_ends = (new Date).getTime() + song.wait_ms;
                        }
                    }
                };
                req.open('get', 'php/PlayingNow.php', true);
                req.send(null);
            }
            // poll for changes every 20 seconds
            setInterval(update_song, 20000);
            // and update the song information
            update_song();
            </script>
<!-- End Now Playing Script -->
```

I want to be able to post it to Twitter like this:  Currently listening to (song_title) by (song_artist)

Here is the code for the PHP file referenced in the script above:

```
<?php // filename: PlayingNow.php
$json = null;
$cache = 'song.json';
// if there is no usuable cache
if (!$json) {
    // retrieve the contents of the URL
    $ch = curl_init('http://bigcountry.streamon.fm/card');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $json = json_decode($res);
    // if the title exists, assume the result to be valid
    if ($json && $json->title) {
        // cache it
        $fp = fopen('song.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $res);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        $json = null;
    }
}
if ($json) {
    $info = array();
    // contains the time in milliseconds
    $info['wait_ms'] = $json->interval->ends_at - 1000 * microtime(true);
    $info['title']   = $json->title ;
    $info['artist']  = $json->artist;
    $info['album']   = $json->album ;
    $info['next']   = $json->next_song;
    $info['image']   = $json->album_art;
    // display a JSON response for the HTML page
    echo json_encode($info);
}
?>
```

Comment: You will need more than javscript to post.

Comment: @Ibu: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: what i mean is the php part is the part that you need to debug. what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I never said I was getting an error.

Comment: do you perhaps know, where the two links you posted went to? they are broken.

Answer (score 1):

The "right" way to do this is to use Twitter's [Web Intents](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/intents), which is designed specifically for this scenario. Take a look at the ["Tweet or Reply to a Tweet"](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/intents#tweet-intent) section. In practice you'll just include the Web Intents script (`http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js`) on your page, create a link, and set its `href`, e.g.:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.innerHTML = "Link Text";
link.href = 'http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Currently listening to "' + songTitle + '" by ' + songArtist;

var parentElement = document.getElementById('SOME_ELEMENTS_ID');
parentElement.appendChild(link);
```

You can add the `url` parameter if you also want the tweet to include your site's URL.

Comment: Let me make sure I have this right.  I include  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
 for the Web Intents script. How exactly to I create a link? Do I use <a href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Currently listening to "' + songTitle + '" by ' + songArtist">Test Text</a> ???

Comment: You create a link with document.createElement, just like you do with the `script` element in your JavaScript code above. I've updated my answer to be more illustrative. This is basic DOM manipulation. MDC has good information on creating and manipulating elements in the DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement

Comment: After creating that link, how do I use it in the context of my site?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question, Luke, and I'm afraid I can't answer it with the information you've given me and the 600 characters this reply box gives me. I hope I've given you some useful information, but I can't guide you any further.